# AutoCompleteTextView - The method setText(String) is undefined for the type String

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, settext

I'm working on AutoCompleteTextView and my end result for my autocompletetextview should be like this [link](https://lh3.ggpht.com/W89eqMvqowxOi0jG4Z_we86NNy3lVzatqRILC6zdmboXkaAP3QRVcdht1ulkf0BvR3Ev) (From and To)
but i have one error at `setText`. it showed me this

> The method setText(String) is undefined for the type String

I don't know what is wrong with it. the error is at FindMePlace.java please help me.

**AutoCompleteDBAdapter.java**

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class AutoCompleteDbAdapter {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_PATH = "data/data/com.example.ukmlocationsearching/databases/";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AcademicLocation";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "UKMRoute";

    private static final String KEY_ROUTEID = "ID_route";
    private static final String KEY_FROMLOCATION = "FromLocation";
    private static final String KEY_TODESTINATION = "ToDestination";
    private static final String KEY_ROUTE1 = "Route1";
    private static final String KEY_ROUTE2 = "Route2";

    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private final Activity mActivity;

    // private final Context myContext;

    private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

            if (dbExist) {
                // do nothing - database already exist
            } else {
                // By calling this method and empty database will be created
                // into the default system path
                // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
                // database with our database.
                this.getReadableDatabase();

                try {
                    copyDataBase();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new Error("Error copying database");

                }
            }
        }

        private boolean checkDataBase() {
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            try {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                // database does't exist yet.
            }

            if (checkDB != null) {
                checkDB.close();
            }
            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

            // Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = mActivity.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

            // Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        }

        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
            // Open the database
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            mDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {

            if (mDb != null)
                mDb.close();

            super.close();

        }

        // Creating Tables
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        }

        // Upgrading database
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }

    }

    public AutoCompleteDbAdapter(Activity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;

    }

    public AutoCompleteDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = this.new DatabaseHelper(mActivity);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Closes the database.
     */
    public void close() {
        if (mDbHelper != null){
        mDbHelper.close();
        }
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Return a Cursor that returns all states (and their state capitals) where
     * the state name begins with the given constraint string.
     * 
     * @param constraint
     *            Specifies the first letters of the states to be listed. If
     *            null, all rows are returned.
     * @return Cursor managed and positioned to the first state, if found
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if query fails
     */
    public Cursor getMatchingFromLocation(String constraint) throws SQLException {

        String queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        if (constraint != null) {
            // Query for any rows where the state name begins with the
            // string specified in constraint.
            //
            // NOTE:
            // If wildcards are to be used in a rawQuery, they must appear
            // in the query parameters, and not in the query string proper.
            // See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3153
            constraint = constraint.trim() + "%";
            queryString += " WHERE FromLocation LIKE ?";
        }
        String params[] = { constraint };

        if (constraint == null) {
            // If no parameters are used in the query,
            // the params arg must be null.
            params = null;
        }
        try {
            Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(queryString, params);
            if (cursor != null) {
                this.mActivity.startManagingCursor(cursor);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("AutoCompleteDbAdapter", e.toString());
            throw e;
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Populates the database with data on states and state capitals.
     * 
     * @param db
     *            The database to be populated; must have the appropriate table
     *            ("state") and columns ("state" and "values") already set up.
     */
    // Adding new Poi
    public void addUkmRoute(UkmRoute Ukmroute) {
        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ROUTEID, Ukmroute.getID()); // ID
        values.put(KEY_FROMLOCATION, Ukmroute.getFromLocation()); //    from
        values.put(KEY_TODESTINATION, Ukmroute.getToDestination()); // to
        values.put(KEY_ROUTE1, Ukmroute.getRoute1()); // route1
        values.put(KEY_ROUTE2, Ukmroute.getRoute2()); //  route2

        // Inserting Row
        mDb.insert(DATABASE_NAME, null, values);
        mDb.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

}
```

**FindMePlace.java**

```
package com.example.series1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FindMePlace extends Activity {

    private AutoCompleteDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private AutoCompleteTextView fromLocation, toDestination;
    Button search;

    class ItemAutoTextAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements
            android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        private AutoCompleteDbAdapter mDbHelper;

        public ItemAutoTextAdapter(AutoCompleteDbAdapter dbHelper) {
            // Call the CursorAdapter constructor with a null Cursor.
            super(FindMePlace.this, null);
            mDbHelper = dbHelper;
        }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @Override
        public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null) {
                return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint);
            }

            Cursor cursor = mDbHelper
                    .getMatchingFromLocation((constraint != null ? constraint
                            .toString() : null));

            return cursor;
        }

        @Override
        public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
            //ubah name table name
            final int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("FromLocation");
            final String str = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            return str;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            /*final String text = convertToString(cursor);
            ((TextView) view).setText(text);*/
            final int fromColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("FromLocation");
            final int toColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ToDestination");
            TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            text1.setText(cursor.getString(fromColumnIndex));
            TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            text2.setText(cursor.getString(toColumnIndex));
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            //final View view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            return view;
        }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result
            // set
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
             //**kene ubah*************capital nama database
            String fromLocation = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("FromLocation"));
            String toDestination = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ToDestination"));

            // Update the parent class's TextView
            //mStateCapitalView.setText(fromLocation);
            fromLocation.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.find_me_place);
        AutoCompleteDbAdapter dbHelper = new AutoCompleteDbAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();

        fromLocation = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.locationTxt);
        toDestination = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.destinationTxt);
        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

         ItemAutoTextAdapter adapter = this.new ItemAutoTextAdapter(dbHelper);
         fromLocation.setAdapter(adapter);
         fromLocation.setOnItemClickListener(adapter);
         toDestination.setAdapter(adapter);
         toDestination.setOnItemClickListener(adapter);

         /*AutoCompleteTextView fromLocation = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.locationTxt);
         ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.country_list, COUNTRIES);
         fromLocation.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); */

         search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.find_me_place, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh please, 100+ lines of code and you don't even tell us which line the error is on?  This will also be a problem, `TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);`, since you are referencing the same TextView as text1.

Comment: sorry.. here is the error  fromLocation.setText("");

Answer (score 1):

```
 String fromLocation = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("FromLocation"));
            String toDestination = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ToDestination"));

            // Update the parent class's TextView
            //mStateCapitalView.setText(fromLocation);
            fromLocation.setText("");
```

`fromLocation` is a String instance.  The String class does not have a `setText()` method.  Either you meant to set the String value, using `fromLocation = ""`, or you meant to set the text of the "from" TextView using `text1.setText("")`.  I don't know which since you did not describe your intention with that line but from the comment, I assume the latter.